# Alguien sabe como puedo agrupar esta consulta en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano.

Estoy haciendo un consulta en una tabla pivote que contiene la relación entre dos tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta resulta es causado por esta consulta.

```
SELECT
    UserID,
    CASE 
        WHEN RespuestaID = 1 THEN Texto
    END ,
    CASE 
        WHEN RespuestaID = 2 THEN Texto
    end 
FROM Respuestas
WHERE RespuestaID in (1,2) AND UserID < 5
```

El resultado que espero es este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen. Lo que intento es agrupar por el UserID. Pero no se como hacerlo dado que en SQLserver no te permite agrupar por un solo campo.

La segunda consulta la hice con múltiples joins a la misma tabla. Pero quiero una consulta más eficiente dado que la que hago ahora es muy lenta.

Este es el ejemplo de la consulta que hago para que me salga los datos agrupados.

```
SELECT 
    t1.UserID,
    t1.Texto as field1,
    t2.Texto as field2
FROM users u
JOIN RespuestasContactos t1
ON t1.UserID = u.id AND t1.RespuestaID = 1
JOIN RespuestasContactos t2
ON t2.UserID = u.id AND t2.RespuestaID = 2
WHERE u.id < 5
```

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que SQL Server no te deja agrupar por un solo campo?

Comment: Esto pasa porque cuando usas un GROUP BY  y los datos no han sido tratados, sql-server intentara hacer también una agrupación con ellos (sacar el resultado en el mismo renglón). Por eso no corría mi primer query, Si solo le agregas el GROUP BY UserID. Esto te dará el error. Si tratas los datos antes de agrupar ya no te da el error.

Comment: sigo sin entender y es que la afirmación es, en principio, incorrecta. SQL Server te deja agrupar por un solo campo, incluso cuando ese campo sea el único de la consulta. Por ejemplo `select campo from tabla group by campo`, es válido, aún cuando no tenga mucho sentido la consulta.

Comment: si yo hago esta consulta me da un error SELECT
    UserID,
    CASE 
        WHEN RespuestaID = 1 THEN Texto
    END ,
    CASE 
        WHEN RespuestaID = 2 THEN Texto
    end 
FROM Respuestas
WHERE RespuestaID in (1,2) AND UserID < 5
GROUP BY UserID

Comment: Si le quitas el GROUP BY funciona.

Comment: Pero la razón no es que SQL Server no soporte agrupar por una sola columna. En general, en todos los motores que cumplen en buena cantidad con el estándar (MySQL, no es uno de ellos)  una consulta _agrupada_ tiene columnas que son parte del criterio de agrupación (que son parte del `group by`, y columnas sobre las que se utiliza alguna función de agregación de datos, tales como `sum(), min(), max(), avg(), count()`. Si lo analizas, no tiene sentido tener una columna sin función de agregación y que no sea parte del criterio de agrupación.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usa una función de agregado. Puede ser MAX() o MIN()

```
SELECT 
    t1.UserID,
    MAX( t1.Texto) as field1,
    MAX( t2.Texto) as field2
FROM users u
JOIN RespuestasContactos t1
ON t1.UserID = u.id AND t1.RespuestaID = 1
JOIN RespuestasContactos t2
ON t2.UserID = u.id AND t2.RespuestaID = 2
WHERE u.id < 5
GROUP BY t1.UserID;
```

Mejor aún sería hacer el JOIN una sola vez.

```
SELECT 
    rc.UserID,
    MAX( CASE WHEN rc.RespuestaID = 1 THEN rc.Texto END) as field1,
    MAX( CASE WHEN rc.RespuestaID = 2 THEN rc.Texto END) as field2
FROM users u
JOIN RespuestasContactos rc
ON rc.UserID = u.id 
WHERE u.id < 5
GROUP BY rc.UserID;
```

Comment: Me puedes explicar si eres tan amable ¿por qué tu si la pudiste agrupar con el campo rc.UserID?. En mi consulta mas simple donde solo pido una tabla no me deja agrupar. Eso no lo entiendo muy en sql server.

Comment: ¿Estás usando MAX() en las otras columnas? ¿Cuál es el error que te arroja?

Comment: No me arroja un error. Pero ya lei más sobre como funciona el GROUP BY, según entendí si no es un dato tratado lo intentara agrupar. Al utilizar la función MAX, MIN, CONCAT, ect. Ya no intentara hacer sobre ellos una agrupación. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me ayudo mucho para entender algunas cosas que desconocía de SQL-server